# Text is missing but no errors

Tags: memoir, multicol, missing, adjmulticol

I have seen some reports here of people complaining that in some rare cases LaTeX does not typeset some of the input text, without any apparent reason. And that the error is so random that a minimum working example (MWE) cannot be reported.

Well, I have found myself in that situation with one of the chapters of my PhD Thesis. I initially typeset my thesis using the **memoir** class and have used a lot of packages.
I have been asked to prepare my thesis for printing and binding in a book format (paper size different than DIN-A4). Therefore, I have had to add yet one more package in order to optimise the use of the paper space. Some of the chapters are written in two parallel running languages using **paracol**, while other chapters are written just in English. In order to optimise the use of the paper area, I have added the **adjmulticol** package.

The chapter where the error occurs is a chapter written only in English, so I invoke the **adjmulticol** package to reduce the overall textwidth in order to limit the number of characters per line for that chapter.

The task to isolate the problem and create a MWE of the problem was daunting at first. However after several iterations I have been able to create a MWE that is small enough to seek for help here.

This code compiles without any errors or warnings. And yet, PDFLaTeX fails to typeset the last words.

This case is driving me mad, because I cannot find a solution for this problem.

Can someone please give me some advice?

If at all possible I want to keep the package **adjmulticol** because after a thorough research I haven't found another package that provides the functionality I need.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright]{memoir}

%%PREAMBLE
\usepackage{adjmulticol}

\setstocksize{24cm}{17cm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{19cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{17mm}{15mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{25mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[classic]
\setlength{\headwidth}{13.8cm}
\makerunningwidth{headings}{\headwidth}
\makeheadposition{headings}{flushright}{flushleft}{flushright}{flushleft}

%%END OF PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0mm}{18mm}

\section{Summary \label{dirichlet_summary}}

The ease of the element to apply Dirichlet boundary conditions on the rotations is equivalent to that of other rotation-free shell elements. And satisfies one of the main design goals set out for the element in 

\end{adjmulticols}

\end{document}
```

PDFLaTeX typesets the text until the end of the second line of the text. And everything in the paragraph after the word **satisfies** is missing.

Thanks in advance!
Pere-Andreu

Comment: Ordinarily, multicols refuses to typeset a single column, and switches to two. Maybe this bug is the reason??

Comment: Yes indeed. If I patch multicol.sty to allow one-column selection, it loses text at the end.

Comment: Thanks Donald, I have included the multicol package in the tags in order to trigger the corresponding alerts.
Hopefully this serves to patch the error, wherever it is.

Comment: @Pere-Andreu multicol itself doesn't allow only one column. There is an open feature request for it https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/150. adjmulticol is trying to force the one column mode but its method is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I have reviewed the feature requests both on GitHub and at The-LaTeX-Project, and it looks to me that it's going to be difficult to have a patch for multicol any time soon. This probably cascades also to the adjmulticol package. Therefore, is there a way to adjust the page layout inside the memoir class? That is, is there a way to change the column width in a 1 column environment? I emphasize the column width because I don't want to change the overall layout of the page (header and footer).

Comment: @Pere-Andreu that is a complete new question so better ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer - only too long for a comment.

A much smaller example is this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0mm}{0mm}
Question\par\vskip 1pt

where is the\\duck?????
\end{adjmulticols}

\end{document}
```

This gives this output, where the last line is lost:

[image]

From the tracing it is clear that the `\vskip` triggers the column balancing and then looses the second column as `adjmulticols` tries to force a one-column layout.

Imho the one column mode of `adjmulticols` is currently not usable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `\@startsection` code in memoir does not like to be typeset in a box.  I'd suggest taking `\section` out of `adjmulticols`:

```
\section{Summary \label{dirichlet_summary}}

\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0mm}{18mm}
\noindent
The ease of the element to apply Dirichlet boundary conditions on
 the rotations is equivalent to that of other rotation-free shell 
 elements. And satisfies one of the main design goals set out for the 
 element in 

\end{adjmulticols}
```

Comment: I have a much simpler example: Only article as class and replace the section by `Summary\par \vskip 1pt`. As soon as one remove the \vskip the word reappears. The amount of the vskip seems not to matter as long it is not zero.

Comment: In the same way that I have isolated a case where the text disappears, I have many many more, where the text does not disappear.
The workaround you suggest may work in this particular case, but this is just a MWE. And as Ulrike is showing, the problem may be triggered in other circumstances as well. In my opinion the MWE should serve to hunt down the root cause of the problem and solve it.
I can do by trying to take the \section out of adjmulticols and then compensate the margins with an \hskip, and I appreciate the suggestion. But I'd rather like to find an overall solution.

Comment: Donald's comments suggest that the problem may be inherited from the multicol package.